# ListView and Dropdown menu android

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-listview, android-actionbar

I have an eclipse generated actionBar dropdown menu, and an array of arrays. And I want to print an array, whose index is the same as the section number, which user has selected. The code below prints the last array in all sections. I have managed to do this with simple TextView before, but I need to do it with ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * current dropdown position.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
    // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                            getString(R.string.title_section1),
                            getString(R.string.title_section2),
                            getString(R.string.title_section3),
                            getString(R.string.title_section4),
                            getString(R.string.title_section5),}), this);



}


private void populateListView(String[] arr) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.da_item, arr);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
};


/**
 * Backward-compatible version of {@link ActionBar#getThemedContext()} that
 * simply returns the {@link android.app.Activity} if
 * <code>getThemedContext</code> is unavailable.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private Context getActionBarThemedContextCompat() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return getActionBar().getThemedContext();
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current dropdown position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);

        String[] laikai = new String[] {"8:30 - 10:00", "10:30 - 12:00", "13:00 - 14:30",
                "14:30 - 16:00", "16:00 - 17:30", "18:00 - 19:30"};
        String[] pirmadienis = new String[] {"x", "y"};
        String[] antradienis = new String[] {"a", "b"};
        String[] treciadienis = new String[] {"c", "d"};
        String[] ketvirtadienis = new String[] {"e", "f"};
        String[] penktadienis = new String[] {"g", "h"};
        String[][] dienos = {pirmadienis, antradienis, treciadienis, ketvirtadienis, penktadienis};         

        for (int i = 0; i < dienos.length; i++) {
            String[] today = dienos[i];
            populateListView(today);
        }

        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an 'array of array' while there is a single element inside each individuals?

Comment: oh, there are multiple elements, I just edited, so it takes less space, sorry for confusing

Comment: Ok. now, where is the "section number"? Are you getting it inside `dummyTextView`?

Comment: I'm not sure about these things, so I added my whole code for you.

Comment: I'm asking about `getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)`. Are you getting an integer? What I understood is, listview will be populated according to this integer. right?

Comment: Yes, Im getting a correct integer there, but I don't know how to populate my listView by using that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm thinking is, you will get a "section number" from `getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)`. Then if section number=0, populate listview with `pirmadienis`,
else if section number=1, populate listview with `antradienis`, and so on.

Here you go:-

```
    /*for (int i = 0; i < dienos.length; i++) {
        String[] today = dienos[i];
        populateListView(today);
    }*/

    dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
            ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
    // instead of the above loop, add this line
     populateListView(dienos[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)]);// if section_number starts with 1, then dienos[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-1]
    return rootView;
```

Comment: Maybe You would also know, how to change text or background color, of a particular element? Not on click, but when populating the list.

Comment: For that, you can not use `ArrayAdapter`. You have to use a custom adapter. Learn the basics from [this toutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).